# Why only Perl backticks executing curl command showing progress bar?

Tags: perl, curl

We I use perl command with **backticks** to execute curl, it shows the progress bar like below:

```sh
root@wetraveller:~# perl -e "print `curl http://127.0.0.1:53424/`"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 53424: Connection refused
```

When I **directly** execute curl, it doesn't show progress bar:

```sh
root@wetraveller:~# curl http://127.0.0.1:53424/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 53424: Connection refused
```

When I use **system** command to execute curl, it doesn't show progress bar

```sh
root@wetraveller:~# perl -e "system('curl http://127.0.0.1:53424/')"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 53424: Connection refused
```

The exact same command is being executed, but if encapsulated in backticks and executed by Perl, the output is different.

So is this a problem with Perl or with Curl?

I understand with -s option we can suppress the output, I'm just curious why the output could be different?

Comment: The problem is `curl`.  For whatever reason, curl decides to spew the banner to stderr when stdout is not a tty.

Comment: Thanks William for your answer! I thought about that too, so I tested like this: curl http://127.0.0.1:2424 2>./error, but the error content is the same without progress bar.

Comment: Perhaps you have a shell function masking curl.  What do you get with `command curl ... 2> error`

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture what the child prints to its STDOUT, backticks associate a pipe with the child's STDOUT.

By default, `curl` displays this meter to STDERR when STDOUT isn't a terminal.

```
$ curl https://pastebin.com/raw/6KdStLY6; echo
A small document

$ curl https://pastebin.com/raw/6KdStLY6 | cat; echo
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16    0    16    0     0     64      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    64
A small document
```

The reason for doing this is to provide a sense of progress when downloading a file to disk.

```
$ curl https://pastebin.com/raw/6KdStLY6 >file; echo done
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16    0    16    0     0    111      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   111
done
```

As you mentioned, this can be prevented by using the `-s` command-line option.

```
$ curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/6KdStLY6 >file; echo done
done
```